# Somar valores em um count do Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

Boa Noite, eu estou com uma dúvida tenho um sistema que roda a seguiten query:

```
SELECT IDUsuario ,COUNT('TotalDeUps') as Total,  FROM uploads
        WHERE Time >= '2018-02-20 00:00:00'
        AND Time < '2018-03-21 00:00:00'
GROUP BY IDUsuario
ORDER BY COUNT("UserID") DESC
```

Eu tenho dentro dessa tabela uploads uma coluna chamda Size , gostaria de saber sé consigo somar os valores do size de um ID pra retornar , eu pensei em algo assim so que não funcionou:

```
SELECT IDUsuario ,COUNT('TotalDeUps') as Total,SUM(Size) as TotalDeUp  FROM uploads
        WHERE Time >= '2018-02-20 00:00:00'
        AND Time < '2018-03-21 00:00:00'
GROUP BY IDUsuario
ORDER BY COUNT("UserID") DESC
```

O resultado foi zero em todas as colunas.

Comment: Talvez você tenha algum registro `NULL`, utilize `COALESCE` para ver se é esse o problema: `SUM(COALESCE(Size, 0))`

Comment: Funcionou amigo , muito obrigado .No caso sé não houvesse um valor null em alguma coluna o SUM(Size)  funcionaria?

Comment: sim, funcionaria

Comment: Coloque sua reposta pra eu dar o Ok , obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente você tem algumas linhas com o valor `NULL` na coluna `size`. Utilize `COALESCE` para considerar esses valores como `0`:

```
...
SUM(COALESCE(Size, 0)) AS TotalDeUp
...
```